# Is it possible in C# to cache the output of the HandleUnknownAction() override?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, caching

Hi and thanks for looking!

## Background

C#, .NET 4.0, MVC, currently running in debug mode on localhost.

## Question

Is it possible to cache the result of the HandleUnknownAction() override?

I am attempting to do so, but it doesn't seem to be caching anything.

Here is an example:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 600, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server, VaryByParam = "actionName")]
protected override void HandleUnknownAction(string actionName)
{    
     View("SomeView").ExecuteResult(ControllerContext);    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can, and here's why:  If you reference the MSDN Documentation on the `OutputCacheAttribute` Class ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx)), you can see the definition as it caches the **output** of the action method.  In this case, the `Controller.HandleUnknownAction()` method returns `void`, so there *is* no output to *cache*.

So, unfortunately, I don't think it works like that.

Comment: Makes sense.  Any recommendation for the next best alternative?  Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt You could always try something like putting the `OutputCache` attribute on a generalized Action Method for your unknown action method call.  That way, `HandleUnknownAction()` wouldn't be cached, but you'd see some benefit of caching the secondary Action Method, and just make a call to `RedirectToAction()` instead of `View()`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem and found that I could use an approach similar to the implementation of the MVC `OutputCacheAttribute`.

I've confirmed that the correct cache headers are sent with the response and that, after a cache miss, `HandleUnknownAction` is not invoked until the output cache expires.

```
protected override void HandleUnknownAction(string actionName)
{
    var Result = View(...);

    using (var Page = new OutputCachedPage(ControllerContext, Result))
    {
        Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context);
    }
}

class OutputCachedPage : Page
{
    readonly ControllerContext ControllerContext;
    readonly ActionResult Result;

    public OutputCachedPage(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult result)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
        if (result == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("result");

        ControllerContext = controllerContext;
        Result = result;
    }

    protected override void FrameworkInitialize()
    {
        base.FrameworkInitialize();

        InitOutputCache(new OutputCacheParameters
            {
                Enabled = true,
                Duration = 600,
                Location = OutputCacheLocation.Any,
                VaryByParam = "*"
            });
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        Result.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext);
    }
}
```

Note that a similar approach can be used within an `ActionFilterAttribute` to provide more sophisticated Output Cache behavior in other scenarios (e.g. cache profiles that expire at set time intervals like :00, :15, :30, :45 minutes past the hour).